# Can this probability be solved? Is more information needed such as how many students in total, can they do multiple sports etc?

Tags: probability

This chart shows information about the sports played by some students:

Two students are selected at random.
[image]
What is the probability that they both play Tennis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a school question, whoever is asking it likely expects you to assume that everyone plays exactly 1 sport, in which case you can determine the number of students (there are 3+8+15+9 boys and 6+12+6+1 girls), and the probability that a student plays a sport by dividing the number of students in that sport by the total number of students.

Without this assumption, all you know is that there are at least 15 boys and at least 12 girls, which is insufficient information.

Comment: Many thanks Wouter, it is a school resource which I am proof reading, so thanks for your quick response.